# Can't get anything to print Ender 3 S1 Pro

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed-leveling

I'm new to 3D printing but got myself an Ender 3 S1 Pro but have been trying to get anything to print for the last week now. I'm pulling out my hair!

When I start a print, a strip of plastic will be put down to clear the nozzle without any stringing or problems but when the main print starts it will string, not adhere properly, come loose, and fail. I have tried everything; the bed is leveled using a piece of paper on all four corners I believe the nozzle is set to the correct height. (with iterations +/-0.3 mm) not changing the flow seems to be correct but if the print doesn't stick to the nozzle, it doesn't adhere to the print bed and comes loose. I have also tried printing with combinations of higher temps and lower speeds but can't get anything to work.

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Some additional details are needed. What type of plastic are you printing with (PLA, ABS, PETG, etc)? What type of bed do you have (glass, PEI, tape, etc)? What type of bed adhesive are you using (glue stick, hair spray, Magigoo)?

Comment: Hi Jurre, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! We'd love to help you out, but this isn't just enough information to work with, please add some photos. Your question is lacking detail and as such is hard to answer without knowing a couple of things about your printer setup. Please [edit] and fill in the [placeholders] in the template I added and then remove the leading `<!--` and trailing `-->` afterwards. This will turn it visible and help us help you find the actual problem.